# Why is my Nissin Di622 Mark II not working properly with my Nikon Z 50?

Tags: flash, nissin, nikon-z50

I have a Nissin Di622 Mark II which I was using nicely with a D40 and a D7100. I don't remember getting overexposed photos.

Now I use a Z 50 and I often get overexposed shots, no matter whether I use direct or indirect (pointing up plus white diffuser card) flash,  sometimes even if I manually decrease flash power via buttons on the flash unit itself.

Is there a setting I am supposed to change, or is the flash not compatible with mirrorless? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not compatible with the new cameras; and it is a discontinued model. But there is a small chance that Nissin can update the firmware to make it compatible if you send it to them and pay $60... I would definitely contact them first before just sending it in.

https://nissindigital.us/pages/firmware-updates

Comment: @inkista, I considered it but I didn't see the Di622 MkII on the list... chances are that it follows with the Di600 that is listed, but IDK for certain.

Comment: Ah. I withdraw the comment. I assumed that column applied to any Di600 models, but you're right.